# python import command is returning "no-module-named..." but the module is clearly in the site packages?

Tags: python, bots, python-import, telegram

I ran the command "import telegram" which produced no "no module named telegram" [as shown this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdZh4.png)

But when I checked my packages in D:\Lib\site-packages the module is clearly there [as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyM7b.png) The commands I used for downloading the telegram package in the windows terminal was "pip install python-telegram-bot". I also tried "pip3 install python-telegram-bot" "pip3 install python-telegram-bot" "python -m install python-telegram-bot" and "python3 -m install python-telegram-bot" but none of them worked.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `virtualenv` to isolation the environment ?
https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

Comment: There are a lots of packages on PyPi that provide a module named `telegram`. Make sure you installed the right one, as it is bound to confusion. What pip command did you use to install the package?

Comment: try uninstalling all the versions of python and try https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to run it with python3 -u ...
[image]

you might have multiple version of python on your machine, tried to identify which by using
python --version
and pip --version

and cheack that they int on the same version of python

[image]

and if you are using pycharm you can install it from there so it will install it in the place it running.

[image]